# When Migrating to .NET 4, Windows asks for user to enable .NET 3.51

Tags: .net-3.5, configuration, .net-4.0, manifest, windows-8

I'm converting a fairly large project from using .NET 3.5 to .NET 4 using Visual Studio 2010. I made sure the Target Framework setting on each project file was set to target .NET 4. I also converted third party dlls to .NET 4 or removed the dependancies. However, when I run my program on Windows 8 dev preview, it always pops up dialogs that asks user to enable .NET 3.51. I found that if I use an *.exe.config file it will suppress the dialog.

How do I check if I missed any assemblies that are still using .NET 3.5 or older references? Or is this caused by some other problem? Does *.exe manifest files affect .NET runtime version?

Please help if you have any idea what is wrong or you ran into something similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause is most likely one of the following in Windows 8 Preview:

1. Throws out "need to install 3.5.1" when it means "4.0"
2. Uses some 3.5.1 assemblies for UI bits regardless of what you have programmed in
3. Windows 8 defaults to 3.5.1 (missing config == reason to fail?) - most likely something hard coded in the OS temporarily

As far as your description, I would guess #3. As long as you are playing with a non-RTMed OS, I would bet there are some issues that people here will not be able to track down.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you happen to know any good tool that will verify if my program still depends on old .net assemblies? For third party dlls, I manually decompiled with ildasm.exe a bunch of .dlls and checked the manifest for referenced version number of .net assemblies. There must be a better way.

Comment: Windows 8 does not contain the 3.5 version of the CLR, but it will be installed on demand if an application requires it.